# Android Kotlin ListAdapter add an empty row when add new item to dataset

Tags: android, addition, listadapter

I have a problem with the ListAdapter (or even with RecyclerView.Adapter). After add new item to the dataset, the ListAdapter auto add an empty row between the new row and last old row.

Below are codes of the funs

```
viewModel.projectEmployees.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { data ->
    data?.let {
        val list = rvAdapter.currentList.toMutableList()
        Log.i("PEF add: dataSet before", list.size.toString())
        list.addAll(it)
        dataSet = list
        Log.i("PEF add: dataSet after", list.size.toString())
        rvAdapter.submitList(list)
        Log.i("PEF add: rvAdapter count", rvAdapter.itemCount.toString())
    }
    (view?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.doOnPreDraw {
        startPostponedEnterTransition()
    }
    stopLoadingAnimation()
})

viewModel.addEmployeeResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    if (it != null) {
        val list = rvAdapter.currentList.toMutableList()
        Log.i("PEF add: dataSet before", list.size.toString())
        list.add(it)
        dataSet = list
        Log.i("PEF add: dataSet after", list.size.toString())
        rvAdapter.submitList(list)
        Log.i("PEF add: rvAdapter count", rvAdapter.itemCount.toString())
    }
    stopLoadingAnimation()
})

viewModel.removeEmployeeResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val list = rvAdapter.currentList.toMutableList()
        Log.i("PEF add: dataSet before", list.size.toString())
        list.removeIf { x -> x.id == it.orEmpty() }
        dataSet = list
        Log.i("PEF remove: dataSet after", list.size.toString())
        rvAdapter.submitList(list)
        Log.i("PEF remove: rvAdapter count", rvAdapter.itemCount.toString())
    }
    stopLoadingAnimation()
})
```

It seems to be that the list adapter has some problems with the current list items. Logcat shows like this

```
2021-12-13 12:00:04.112 5841-5841/com.gndev.project_portal I/PEF add: dataSet before: 3
2021-12-13 12:00:04.112 5841-5841/com.gndev.project_portal I/PEF add: dataSet after: 4
2021-12-13 12:00:04.112 5841-5841/com.gndev.project_portal I/PEF add: rvAdapter count: 3
```

I tried many solutions but they are not working somehow. Anyone has the same problem?

[image]

```
fun bind(item: CompactEmployeeModel) = with(itemView) {
    GlideUtils.load(
        context,
        findViewById<ShapeableImageView>(R.id.ivAvatar),
        item.avatarUrl,
        R.drawable.ic_employee
    )
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvFullName).text = item.fullName
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPhoneNumber).text = item.phoneNumber

    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(
        itemView,
        "transition_employee_detail_${item.id!!}"
    )
}
```

Comment: can you add your onBind() and stopLoadingAnimation() snippets here?

Comment: you should call notifyDatasetChanged rather than submitList

Comment: @YukiN but the submitlist is the only way to update ListAdapter dataset I guess

Comment: @RajasekaranM I use simple ListAdapter so only bind method. Added!

Comment: Use recyclerview.adapter and linearLayoutManager instead

Comment: @YukiN as I already told, same problem